# Interrupt And Continue Vagrant Adding Box

Tags: macos, vagrant

I added box to vagrant yesterday. But there was internet problem that caused adding box not move. So, I interrupted the adding process with Ctrl + c.
The question, can I continue adding process? I see vagrant has download about 50%.

Here I attach the screenshot[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

My experience has shown that you are much better off to try downloading again from the beginning.
But first you will most likely have to delete the temporarily downloaded files before it will let you begin once again.  If you try and get an error, delete all the files under the following directories:

Windows:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.vagrant.d\tmp\*
```

Mac OS:

```
~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*
```